# Chromium kiosk mode : Fullscreen and remove address bar

Tags: chromium, kiosk-mode

I am trying to run chromium browser in kiosk mode in raspberry pi 3(Official Jessie ).

Here is i've added in my autostart file

```
@point-rpi
@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms

@chromium-browser --kisok www.fb.com
```

This works fine but some problem occured.

Browser is not opened in full window also the address bar is still present in chromium

So how can i remove above two items

Comment: @JasonVearncombe  let me try

Answer (score 12):

For full kiosk mode, you might want to hide the Chromium scrollbars, always, for a webpage. This does not disable scrolling on a touchscreen. It just disables the scrollbars.

Using the --enable-features flag with chromium-browser did the trick for me.

```
--enable-features=OverlayScrollbar,OverlayScrollbarFlashAfterAnyScrollUpdate,OverlayScrollbarFlashWhenMouseEnter
```

And this is my full command:

```
    /usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --noerrdialogs --enable-features=OverlayScrollbar --disable-restore-session-state http://10.10.0.16:8123
```

Also, to hide the mouse cursor entirely, I have changed the X command on my raspbian in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf from `xserver-command=X` to `xserver-command=X -nocursor`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue ... I eventually used this in a .xinitrc file in the home directory.

```
#Disable DPMS.
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank

#Lets remove a lock file that could be caused due to a crash.
rm /home/pi/.config/chromium/SingletonLock

while true; do
    # Clean up previously running apps, gracefully at first then harshly
    killall -TERM chromium-browser 2>/dev/null;
    killall -TERM matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;

    sleep 2;

    killall -9 chromium-browser 2>/dev/null;
    killall -9 matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;

    # Launch window manager without title bar.
    exec matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no -use_cursor no -theme bluebox &

    # Run unclutter
    unclutter &

    # Launch browser.
    chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk --noerrdialogs --disable-translate --disable-cache --disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --disk-cache-size=1 --app=http://URL_TO_GO_TO

done;
```

I use the matchbox windows manager and had to make some other tweaks, but this is what I am using.

Comment: @Jabaa: It is in this line of code ... I use matchbox to hide my cursor: exec matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no -use_cursor no -theme bluebox &

I currently have 703 PIs in the field running all our displays for our branches (Sports Betting Industry) and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing to this

```
#@xscreensaver -no-splash  # comment this line out to disable screensaver
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk http://www.fb.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

For those arriving here from Google:

The answer to this question will vary, depending on how you have setup Chromium to automatically run (using OpenBox, Xsession, etc). The answer will also vary depending on what version of Raspbian you are running (Full, Lite, or Super Lite).

I would recommend using the following article to correctly set up your Raspberry Pi to perform this action: https://blockdev.io/raspberry-pi-2-and-3-chromium-in-kiosk-mode/ .

**NOTE**: While this article is great at walking you through how to correctly setup your pi to run in a proper kiosk mode, you will need to change the "sed"/"@sed" command(s) if you don't wish to be prompted about Chromium not exiting correctly. To fix this, please change your "sed" (or "@sed") command(s) to the following:

- sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
- sed -i ‘s/”exit_type”: “Crashed”/”exit_type”: “Normal”/’ ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

If you are supposed to use "@sed", then please provide a "@" before each of the commands above.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a user, op in this example, for autologin at boot

   > adduser op
   >  
   >   usermod –a –G op op
   >   usermod –a –G users op 
   >   usermod –a –G audio op
   >   usermod –a –G video op
2. Configure the autologin by creating the file /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf with the following content

   > [Service]
   >   ExecStart=
   >   ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin op --noclear %I 38400 linux
3. Enable autologin with the following command

   > systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
4. Impersonate the op user with the following command

   > sudo su - op
5. Insert at the end of the /home/op/.bashrc the following lines

   > if [ $(tty) == "/dev/tty1" ]; then
   >       while true; do startx -- -nocursor; echo "Again [$?]..."; done
   >   fi
6. Create the file /home/op/.xinitrc with the following content

   > chromium-browser --window-size=7000,7000 --start-fullscreen --kiosk -app=http://www.fb.com/
7. Reboot

Answer (score 1):

Other way to hide cursor in Raspbian is by using `unclutter`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unclutter
```

then in the script, insert this line:

```
unclutter &
```