# web browsers without controls and addressbar

Tags: java, web, webkit

I've been trying to research for existing web browsers that do not have an address bar or additional controls on the UI. Ideally a web browser that has just the window frame. The reason is that I am writing a web application, which ideally I do not want the user to have the ability to navigate to other websites or have the ability to navigate backwards/forwards etc. Obviously I can write additional code that can prevent people from navigating other side/ backwards, etc, but ideally would like a clean Window for the user to work from.

So far i've explored the option of building a web browser UI using JavaFX. However the web application is built using Angular and the JavaFX web browser window flickers from time to time during a screen transition.

If there is anyone that can provide a recommendation of such a browser that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious if you have already looked into Kiosk modes for browsers as that is built in and meant to display a single website. If chromium has that then could could use that.

[Chromium kiosk mode no address bar or menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503701/chromium-kiosk-mode-fullscreen-and-remove-address-bar)

Edit:
https://github.com/chromium/chromium