# Chromium Kiosk Mode lock down every way to escape the intended webpage (Tabs, Bookmarks, Settings, etc.)

Tags: chromium, kiosk, kiosk-mode, wayland

I would like to use the chromium browser in a project, where only one webpage is shown in fullscreen. The user needs full mouse and keyboard support, so I plan to use wayland as desktop environment.

Chromium Kiosk mode `--kiosk` is a great start ([see also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42503701/2590485)), but with full keyboard access the user still can open more than one tab (Ctrl-T), set bookmarks (Ctrl-D) thus showing the bookmarks bar, and probably much more I am not aware of...

**Question**: how do I lock down the chromium browser as much as possible, so that nothing can be changed by the user, and the intended page cannot be escaped...?

Thanks!